# Python3 - Como fazer parar de pedir determinado número?

Tags: python, programação-estruturada

**Sei que para o presente código é preciso usar uma estrutura de repetição, podendo ser while uma dessas. Mas não consegui associar tal comando ao meu código.**

**Afim de facilitar o entendimento, deixo aqui a questão:**

> Um programa que peça vários números ao usuário e exiba se ele é par
> ou ímpar. O programa para de pedir número quando o usuário digitar 0.

Código fiz:

```
print() #Espaço1
print('Digite apenas números ')
print() #E2
numpar = 0
numimpar = 0
while True:
numero = int(input('Digite o número: '))
for i in while():
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        numpar += 1
    else:
        numimpar += 1
print(f'Pares {numpar}')
print(f'Impares {numimpar}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Mudando um pouco seu programa teríamos:

```
print()
print('Digite apenas números ')
print()

numero = int(input('Digite o número: '))

while numero != 0:
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        print(f'o número {numero} é par')
    else:
        print(f'o número {numero} é impar')
    print()
    numero = int(input('Digite o número: '))
```

Lembre-se que o comando `while` é seguido de uma condição

Espero que ajude

Comment: Usei o seguinte:

Comment: Olá! Caro colega, @PauloMarques, obrigado pelo toque.